# why data is showing undefined in ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am calling an ajax call , in which providing an array with data, when I am going to debug this code in console in shows me `data` is `undefined` why ?

Comment: I'm surprised it's running at all, that code tries to read the value of an undeclared symbol. You must have a `var data` somewhere you're not showing.

Comment: data is declared above

Comment: Not in the scope it's used it isn't.

Comment: so how do I do that?

Answer (score 1):

In the `success` function of your first ajax call, you have this:

```
success: function (response) {
    orderId = data;
    if (data != null) {
        orderStatus = "Order has been placed successfully.";
    }
}
```

Note that you've called the argument to the callback `response`, but then used `data`. The code as quoted should fail with a `ReferenceError`, because there's no `data` in scope in that callback (the only place you have `var data` is *inside* another callback). I assume you have it declared in code you haven't quoted.

I assume you meant `response`, not `data`:

```
success: function (response) {
    orderId = response;
    if (response != null) {
        orderStatus = "Order has been placed successfully.";
    }
}
```

Comment: you are right. I need my order to be successful ? how would I do that

Comment: should I declare `var data` at the top?

Comment: @QadeerMangrio: No, you should do what I showed you in the answer. The code's pretty unclear, but you may also need to [read this question's answers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call).